# Null in standard input in Java

Tags: java, stream

I am working on small program where user inputs text in standard input and then this text is returned with proper alignment.

My main block of code where input is being read line by line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
   try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {                               
            for (String nextLine, line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = nextLine) {                
                nextLine = br.readLine();
                // Work with "line"
            }
   }
   catch (IOException ex) {         
        System.exit(-1);
   }
}
```

But input is never read all. Always last line is missing and `line` is never `null`. After little debugging I found out that `br.readLine()` on line `nextLine = br.readLine();` doesn't return anything (literally it doesn't return anything. No exception is thrown though.) and program keeps running but is not executing any other lines of my code. I also tried reading from file and this problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your input comes from standard input, you have to let your program know when the input ends. Otherwise it will keep waiting for the next input to be entered.

Therefore you should decide on some character or String that would mark the end of the input.

For example, here typing `done` would end the loop :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
   try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {                               
            for (String nextLine, line = br.readLine(); line != null && !line.equals("done"); line = nextLine) {                
                nextLine = br.readLine();
                // Work with "line"
            }
   }
   catch (IOException ex) {         
        System.exit(-1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is probably because `readLine()` blocks until a new line is available or the stream reaches `EOF` (which never happens when you read from  `System.in`). 
You never get the last input because your loop always processes the previously read line.

Try this:

```
for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;)
```

and break from this loop when you've read all the input you need, ex:

```
 if(line.equals("finish")){
     break;
 }
```